# How can I figure to connect my NVR in this topology?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, ethernet, ipv4

I´m trying to configure a NVR to my company´s network.

There is a router from which I will assign a fixed public IP to the NVR.

I could connect the NVR directly to the Router which has 5 different interfaces with a public IP each one, but then if I do that I wouldn´t be able to access the NVR directly from my company´s network.

I wonder If I could connect the router interface that I´m going to use as well as the NVR to a switch, then assign public IP to the NVR. at this point I need to know how can I make the NVR accesible to the other network users that are using a different public IP.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying your company network can't access the Internet (public address)? A diagram would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

NVR as in network video recorder? Do not connect it directly to the public IP network as most devices are insecure. The easy - and unsafe - method is to configure your router with port forwarding to pass requests to the private IP address of the NVR. This is unsafe, as all security issues of the device on that port could be exploited from the Internet and your network might be compromised that way.

The safe method to do this is to create VPN access to the network and secure access that way.

In order to find your network, you'll need a static IP address or some kind of dynamic DNS service that gets updated when the IP address changes.